# Java: read an escape character as '\' followed by a char?

Tags: java, escaping

I am writing the scanner of a compiler, and I'm experiencing troubles with the input " {\0} ".
What my scanner should do is: skip blank, recognize '{', recognize unvalid char, recognize '}', skip blank, detect eof. Instead, it will just skip the \0 .

My scanner is done in such way, that it'll skip any "useless" character (value less or equal than ' '). For this reason, the \0 char will be skipped, instead of being processed as an unvalid character constant (I didn't implement this error case yet, but anyway my code doesn't get in the `readCharConst(Token t)` function in thi case...). What I would like to know is what I should do in order to have it processing '\0' as '\' followed by '0' and not as a single character.

Here are some of my functions:

```
public Token next() {
    while (ch <= ' ') {
        nextCh(); // skip blanks, tabs, eols
    }
    Token t = new Token(Kind.none, line, col);
    switch (ch) {
    // cases for identifiers, numbers, meta-chars, ...
    case '\'':
     readCharConst(t);
         break; 
    default:
     error(t, Message.INVALID_CHAR, ch);
     nextCh();
     t.kind = Kind.none;
     }
     return t;
}
```

with:

```
public void nextCh() {
    try {
        ch = (char) in.read();
        if (ch == LF) { // detects new_line
            col = 0;
            line++;
        } else if (ch != EOF) { // do not increment col for EOF
            col++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ch = EOF;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and:

```
private void readCharConst(Token t) {
    nextCh();
    if (ch == '\'') {
        error(t, Message.EMPTY_CHARCONST);
    } else {
        t.val = (int) ch;
        t.kind = Kind.charConst;
        nextCh();
        if (ch != '\'') {
            error(t, Message.MISSING_QUOTE);
        }
        nextCh();
    }
}
```

NB: I kind of solved my problem by replacing the `while (ch <= ' ')` by a `while(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\r'|| ch == '\b' || ch == '\f' || ch == '\"' || ch == '\'' || ch == '\\')`, in order to detect all the escape sequences and treat the rest with the default condition. Nevertheless, my course-slides say that \r, \n, \t should be treated as char constants (which in my opinion brings me to a stall, unless I can find a way of treating the sequances as '\' followed by a char).

Comment: why down-voting without commenting? if you think my question is silly (it might be, in the end I'm here to learn), I'd ike to know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think I got it. It's not about reading the '\' but rather only skipping the right characters. Those characters are the escape sequences which value is lower than ' ' (ASCII val in decimal: 32). Therefore, the characters to skip are `'\b'`(val:8), `'\t'`(val:9), `'\n'`(val:10), `'\f'`(val:12), `'\r'`(val:13), while all the others will be handled by the default case of my switch. I therefore changed my while to:

```
while (ch == ' ' || ch == '\b' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\f' || ch == '\r')
// skip blanks and all esc. seq. with value < ' ' (others, like '\'' might need to be treated)          
nextCh();
```

And in fact the case '\'' had nothing to do here (doesn't match the input I gave), so this is probably why I was down-voted. That case only comes into play if I'm trying to recognize the escape sequences mentioned above, should they explicitly appear in the input (for example,  input `" '\\n' "`).